# How do I prevent QSplitter from hiding child widgets completely?

Tags: c++, qt, qsplitter

I have a horizontal `QSplitter` with two child `QWidget` objects. Now, when user drags the splitter handle to the right beyond a certain threshold (which, I assume, depends on child's minimum size), the right `QWidget` disappears with a snap. `setSizePolicy`, `setMinimumSize` do not help.

Furthermore, `hideEvent` is not triggered, and I can't even detect when my widget gets hidden. I tried using `resizeEvent`, but both its old and new width parameters seem to have undocumented weird values -- sometimes it's 0, sometimes -1. Even if there is a system to it, it can change with next Qt release.

Ideally, I would like to turn this disappearing behaviour off completely. As a compromise, I would be grateful for an idea how to detect it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to prevent a certain `widget` from collapsing then you need...

```
int index = my_splitter.indexOf(widget);
my_splitter.setCollapsible(index, false);
```

Documentation is [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#childrenCollapsible-prop).

Comment: Ha! You are correct -- they call it 'collapse', not 'hide'. Solves my current problem, thanks. Out of idle curiosity: is there a way to detect this collapse event after it happens?

Comment: (_is there a way to detect this collapse event after it happens?_) If you install an event filter on the widget that you want to detect it collapsing, you'll notice a [QInputMethodQueryEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qinputmethodqueryevent.html) triggered.