# How to prevent QSplitter child from collapsing before completely minimizing its size to 0

Tags: c++, qt, qsplitter

I'm trying to get a horizontal `QSplitter` to allow me to resize one of its children's width to 0 without it collapsing before reaching the edge.

Here's an example of `QSplitter` with 2 children, a `QWidget`, and a `QPushButton`, where the button collapses before I drag it to the edge:

[image: Unwanted collapsing behavior]

Minimal Reproducible example:

```
QSplitter *splitter = new QSplitter();
QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("button");

widget->setStyleSheet("background: darkblue;");

splitter->addWidget(button);
splitter->addWidget(widget);

splitter->show();

splitter->setMinimumSize(100,100);
```

I tried:

- [setChildrenCollapsible(false)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsplitter.html#childrenCollapsible-prop), but it results in the button not budging below a certain width, here's how it looks:

  [image: Button not budging]
- Setting minimum width of `QSplitter` and its children to 0.

  - Setting their sizes manually below the size they won't go below.
  - Changing size policy to `ignored`.

All made no difference.

The closest question to my case that I found here is this one: [How do I prevent QSplitter from hiding child widgets completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520905/how-do-i-prevent-qsplitter-from-hiding-child-widgets-completely/41520959#comment134619518_41520959), which did not help.

Using an event filter, I noticed a [QInputMethodQueryEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qinputmethodqueryevent.html) triggered when the button collapses, but I do not know how to use that.

I also noticed that the behavior I'm looking to achieve is possible with `QWidget`, `QFrame`, here's how it looks with 2 `QWidgets` in a `QSplitter`:

[image: Normal collapsing behavior]

Based on this observation, I managed to find a workaround, by placing the widget I need (button for example) inside a `QWidget`, and making the container widget a child of `QSplitter`, and it works, but I'd rather avoid using this method.

What is causing this behavior? And how do I change it so that the button resizes until its width reaches 0 without collapsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the button is not resized is because `QSplitter` respects size policy of the button. Setting it to `QSizePolicy::Ignored` allows `QSplitter` to freely resize the button.

```cpp
auto * button = new QPushButton();
button->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
```